# HTML5 : progress bar on click

Tags: html, progress-bar

i have an html file that has a clickable content

```
<tr onclick="callfn('Afile.jsp?param1=<%= value1%>');" id="contenttr">
```

where callfn is a function in a javascript file that loads images.
since this function takes time, i have to display a progress bar during the load.

Is it possible for me to add the progress bar tag for the same?
if so how can i do it?

Help!! :(

Comment: jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldnt work with the progress element, so ended up using the gif image to show the progress bar

http://ajaxload.info/
helped me to get a good gif image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not 100% what you need, bu I've created a simple experiment with drag&drop functionality for my personal needs. Because this process involves quite a lot of code writing i'm posting on my site. You can take a look on the source code here and adapt for your requirements: http://hellopixel.net/experiments/javascript/drag-drop/.